Why Separable Degree?
Let $L/k$ be a field extension. Is there any significance to (perhaps categorical) the Homset $\text{Hom}_{k-\mathsf{Alg}}(L, \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the algebraic closure of $L$? It seems to be central piece to Galois extensions: normality amounts to $\text{Aut}(L/k)$ act transitively on it, and separability to $|\text{Hom}_{k-\mathsf{Alg}}(L, \Omega)| = [L:k]$. What makes it natural to consider this set? Furthermore, for separability, how would this definition be modified for infinite extensions. Is there some action going on?

First, consider the case where $L$ is generated over $k$ by an algebraic element $x$.
Then a $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi : L \to \Omega$ is uniquely determined by $\phi (x)$ – that is what it means for $x$ to generate – and moreover there is a $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi : L \to \Omega$ with $\phi (x) = x'$ if and only if $x'$ satisfies the same minimal polynomial over $k$ as $x$.
Hence, in this case, the set of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $L \to \Omega$ can be identified with the set of algebraic conjugates of $x$ (well, $\phi (x)$ for some $\phi : L \to \Omega$, to be precise).
The meaning of separability becomes clear: it means the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k$ factors over $\Omega$ into linear factors with no repeated factors.
I hope you agree that the set of algebraic conjugates of an element, and the action of the Galois group on it, is something central in (classical) Galois theory.
The change in perspective from the set of algebraic conjugates of a particular element to the set of embeddings into $\Omega$ is, in some sense, the analogue of going from classical Riemannian geometry with coordinate transformations and covariant/contravariant tensors and so on to the modern coordinate-free manifold formalism with charts and tangent/cotangent bundles and so on.
In general, an algebraic extension need not be generated by a single element (not even if finite), so it is harder to give a classical-style explanation of the set of embeddings into $\Omega$.
Still, if $L$ is generated by some subset $X \subseteq L$, then a $k$-algebra homomorphism $L \to \Omega$ is determined by the restriction $X \to \Omega$, i.e. the map $\textrm{Hom}_{k\textbf{-Alg}} (L, \Omega) \to \Omega^X$ sending $\phi$ to the map $x \mapsto \phi (x)$ is injective.
A general algebraic extension is separable if and only if it is a union of finite separable extensions.
I do not think separability can be expressed as a property of the set of embeddings into $\Omega$ as an abstract set with an action of the Galois group.
After all, if $L$ is a purely inseparable extension generated by a single element, then there is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $L \to \Omega$ – how are we going to distinguish it from the base field $k$, which also has a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $k \to \Omega$?
(There is, however, an algebraic characterisation of separability not based on counting: $L$ is separable if and only if $L \otimes_k \Omega$ is a reduced $k$-algebra, i.e. the only nilpotent is $0$.)
